# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un archivo php se ejecute con post ( formulario ) y no se ejectute desde navegador?

Tags: php

Hola yo lo he intentado mediante el archivo htacces, pero me funciona solo en chrome, en explorer, opera mozilla no me funciona, he hecho esto:

```
<Files "Logout.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "validar.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "Comprobar.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Si intentas desde navegador no permiten pero si accedes mediante una llamada de un post entonces tampoco te deja, en chrome si me deja raramente pero en los otros navegadores no?

¿alguna solución para esto?

Comment: El archivo htaccess debería controlar el acceso a nivel de servidor, no tiene sentido que te funcione en Chrome pero no en Explorer, Opera o Mozilla (al menos no si lo que tienes es lo compartido).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás utilizando el método `POST` podrías preguntar si los campos del formulario que estás intentando enviar están definidos o no.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['value'])){
        // my code
    } else {
        header('Location: default_page.php');
    }
?>
```

Si accedes a la página directamente estos valores no estarán definidos y se redireccionará al usuario a otra página.

Comment: muchas gracias y si fuese por ejemplo Logout desde una etiqueta <a> ?

Comment: Especifícame un poco más, disculpa

Comment: @belixco  Stack Overflow no es un foro donde se van publicando posts y más posts pidiendo clarificación, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde la pregunta va en una sección y las respuestas en otra, y puedes dejar comentarios debajo de las otras publicaciones. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y así ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: si por ejemplo tengo un código que es <a href= "logout.php"  , qué hago para que no se pueda acceder a logout desde el navegador? Gracias.

Comment: Los otros dos con post ya me funciona, cómo tu dijiste, gracias, el problema es cuando está en un tag <a>

Comment: Acceder a través del href es igual a acceder a través de la barra de direcciones. Si permites una cosa también permites la otra hasta donde sé yo.